# Get variable values from config file

Tags: bash, parsing

I have one config file with some variables eg below but my command only read some variable value, I cant read all values in config file. Seems only read values with numbers.
what is better way to read all possible type of values ?

```
sed -n '/^SENDER=\([*]*\)$/s//\1/p' "Config_file"
```

Config_file:

```
# Some text
LOGLEVEL=1

# Some text
THRESHOLD=0

# Some text
SAVERULES=0

# Some text
LINESTOSEARCH=1000000

# Some text
HTDOCSFOLDER=/var/www/

# Some text
LOG=/var/log/access.log

# Some text
SENDER=xpto@xpto.bar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `/^SENDER=\([*]*\)$/s//\1/p`
>
> `[*]`

What a kind of syntax is that? Any char is `.` in regexps.

```
$ sed -n '/^SENDER=\(.*\)$/s//\1/p' <<< SENDER=xpto@xpto.bar
xpto@xpto.bar
```

But I doubt you’ve chosen a right way to do what you are doing. What for do you need this? Most probably, it would be much better to read the whole config in array.

```
#!/bin/bash

readconfig() {
    local ARRAY="$1"
    local KEY VALUE 
    local IFS='='
    declare -g -A "$ARRAY"
    while read; do
        # here assumed that comments may not be indented
        [[ $REPLY == [^#]*[^$IFS]${IFS}[^$IFS]* ]] && {
            read KEY VALUE <<< "$REPLY"
            [[ -n $KEY ]] || continue
            eval "$ARRAY[$KEY]=\"\$VALUE\""
        }
    done 
}

readconfig MYCONFIG < "Config_file"

echo ${MYCONFIG[SENDER]}
```